# String.Contains() does not find match from For Loop List Item

Tags: c#, arrays, list, for-loop

I split a `string` into a `array` with each previous word concat with the next.

String 1: `The Earth is the third planet from the sun.`

```
The
The Earth
The Earth is
The Earth is the
The Earth is the third
The Earth is the third planet
The Earth is the third planet from
The Earth is the third planet from the
The Earth is the third planet from the sun.
```

---

I want to search a second string for a match from the List.

String 2: `The Earth is the planet we live on.`

The match should be `The Earth is the`.

---

However my `string.Contains()` does not detect the match from `variations[m]`.

http://rextester.com/BDYV53887

**C#**

```
string sentence1 = "The Earth is the third planet from the sun.";
string sentence2 = "The Earth is the planet we live on.";

string[] words = sentence1.Split(' ');

List<string> variations = new List<string>();


// List of Word variations
//
string combined = string.Empty;
for (var i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    combined = string.Join(" ", combined, words[i]);
    variations.Add(combined);
}

// Words Match
//
string match = string.Empty;
for (int m = 0; m < variations.Count; m++)
{
    if (sentence2.Contains(variations[m])) // not working, "The Earth is the" not found
    {
        match = variations[m];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `variations[m]` start with a space.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I didn't notice that. TrimStart() seems to have solved it.

Comment: Yep, just don't add it or `TrimStart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combined = string.Join(" ", combined, words[i]);
```

this statement when run on the first word (`i = 0`) joins the empty string with a `words[0]`.

This leads you to having an extra space between the first word.

The straightforward fix would be

```
if (i == 0) {
    combined = words[i];
} else {
    combined = string.Join(" ", combined, words[i]);
}
```

That is: you're checking whether it's a first word or not and act correspondingly.